# Why does configuration option stay red?

Tags: configuration

I am very new to CiviCRM. I am setting the Configuration Checklist options. After setting one, and saving, it remains red. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

The "Configuration Checklist" is just a set of links - the color is just an indication of whether or not you've clicked on it.  In many cases, there's no definitive way for CiviCRM to know whether the answer you gave is "correct".  For instance, you may not have set a default state/province because you don't want one, not because you forgot to.

That said: Some configurations MUST be set.  Those will show up at **Administer menu » Administration Console » System Status** if they're not configured.

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing the Configuration Checklist page after you have visited the links it suggests. They should change from red.